# Ubuntu RVM install issue rvm_ruby_src_path not set

Tags: rvm

Following instructions from http://web2linux.com/installing-rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/  I get to the following line:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

returns:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p0 to 
mv: cannot move `/tmp/rvm_src_18035/ruby-1.9.2-p0' to `': No such file or directory
~/.rvm/scripts/manage: line 1237: ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #extracted to : command not found
Running autoconf
Error running 'autoconf', please check ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/autoconf*.log
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoconf not run successfully?
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please check ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/make*.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

looking at .rvm/scripts/manage it seems that $rvm_ruby_src_path is not set.  Am I missing anything in my setup? Below are more details on my environment:

```
$ rvm info

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux host 2.6.32-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 20 14:21:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.0.7 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "~/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    BUNDLE_PATH:  ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux

$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - ~/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reinstalled my mac, and got the same problem.

Edit: after I run rvm update && rvm reload, it works！

Comment: It worked! For some reason I missed the "rvm reload". Thanks!